# Jenkins pipeline with userinput extendedChoice returns the values with [ ] at the beginning and end

Tags: jenkins, devops, pipeline

I added the below to the pipeline so while the pipeline is running - at some stage I want the user to choose from the parameters but the output returns with parentheses at beginning and end.

```
def envs = input(id: 'Upgarde', message: 'On which customer do you want to apply the upgrade?', submitter: 'admin', ok: 'Submit', parameters: [extendedChoice(defaultValue: env.ENV.split().toString(), description: '', descriptionPropertyValue: env.ENV.split().toString(), multiSelectDelimiter: '', name: 'Customers to upgrade', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT', value: env.ENV.split().toString())]).split(',')
```

Screenshot from the Jenkins UI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjWXf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by added `.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")`